# Integromat Make, Send dynamically generated form_data to API in a module

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I am making a custom app in make that sends data to our system. I am trying to send custom data to our system, I could able to generate dynamic mapping parameters using "RPC" I could able to see them in the UI in the scenarios.

[image]

```
["rpc://GetCustomFields"]
```

But I could not able to send the form the module to our system.

Things I tryed

1. Make an RPC which generates code that matchs the body as shown in the documentation and place that RPC in the body of the module

   [
   {
   "custom_field01": "{{parameters.custom_field01}}"
   }
   ]

Use that RPC to generate dynamic code to get data from the custom fields

```
{
    "url": "/test_url",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "JWT token"
    },
    "body": {
    "standard_fields":{
    "FIRSTNAME":"{{parameters.FIRSTNAME}}",
    "LASTNAME":"{{parameters.LASTNAME}}",
    "SALUTATION": "{{parameters.SALUTATION}}",
    "TITLE": "{{parameters.TITLE}}",
    "COUNTRY": "{{parameters.COUNTRY}}",
    "CITY": "{{parameters.CITY}}",
    "ZIP": "{{parameters.ZIP}}",
    "ADDRESS": "{{parameters.ADDRESS}}",
    "ORGANIZATION": "{{parameters.ORGANIZATION}}"
    },
    "custom_fields":"rpc://sendCustomFields"
    },
    "response": {
        "output": "{{body}}"
    }
}
```

But Unfortunately what I get in request call is this

```
{
    "custom_fields": "rpc://app%43randomText-8jkh96@1/sendCustomFields",
    "standard_fields": {
        "SALUTATION": "Herr"
    }
}
```

2. Try to build custom ILM function to generate dynamic code

   function helperSendCustomFields() {
   let customField = {};
   customField.custom_field01 = "{{parameters.custom_field01}}";
   return customField;
   }

In module connection

```
{
    "url": "/test_url",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "JWT token"
    },
    "body": {
    "standard_fields":{
    "FIRSTNAME":"{{parameters.FIRSTNAME}}",
    "LASTNAME":"{{parameters.LASTNAME}}",
    "SALUTATION": "{{parameters.SALUTATION}}",
    "TITLE": "{{parameters.TITLE}}",
    "COUNTRY": "{{parameters.COUNTRY}}",
    "CITY": "{{parameters.CITY}}",
    "ZIP": "{{parameters.ZIP}}",
    "ADDRESS": "{{parameters.ADDRESS}}",
    "ORGANIZATION": "{{parameters.ORGANIZATION}}"
    },
    "custom_fields":"{{helperSendCustomFields()}}"
    },
    "response": {
        "output": "{{body}}"
    }
}
```

what I get in the request call is

```
{
    "custom_fields": {
        "custom_field01": "{{parameters.custom_field01}}"
    },
    "standard_fields": {
        "SALUTATION": "Herr"
    }
}
```

Please any idea's to get data from the dynamically generated form in Make application

Answer (score 0):

I finally found solution, I requested IML functions which was accepted and then I used it dynamically generate the body of the module

for example, I created a method in IML

```
function generateBodyForCreateContact(parameters) {
    return requiredBody;
}
```

parameters are the data available in bundle and use it in the module

```
"body": "{{generateBodyForCreateContact(parameters)}}"
```

Finally now I have dynamic body which changes with the data inputted from the other make events